# Workflow Foundation 4 - Activity Design

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have an existing project which is an application that runs several flows, calling other processes to execute some of the flow.
The current implementation uses [Stateless State Machine](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/) for handling the flow.
I am now rewriting this project (due to several reasons) and I am trying to use WF4 for the flow control.

My question is this: Should I build a workflow (flowchart) that only handles the flow and calls an external class for the actual business logic, or should I implement the Business Logic inside the Workflow Activities (Mainly Code Activities)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to extract some general info for deciding in your transitions, separation of the logic class will protect you against
W.F. version changes. So you only need to call your biz logic methods
in your W.F. and remain the logic part unchanged.